# Linux: change default port for NTPD via iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, ntpd

My ISP blocks outbound udp port 123 and it caused my router can not update the time via NTPD.

I got some information about change NTP default port 123 via iptables for this case, but can't make it work.

My case seems like this:

Send request: 
My Router(src_port:123) -> My Router(iptables change 123 to 1077) -> ISP -> NTP server(1077 for NTP service)

Receive response: 
My Router(src_port:123) <- My Router(iptables change 1077 to 123) <- ISP <- NTP server(1077 for NTP service)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to change the local port, you can use a basic SNAT rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wan -p udp --sport 123 -j SNAT --to :2345

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wan -p udp --sport 123 -j SNAT --random

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wan -p udp --sport 123 -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 2345-6789

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wan -p udp --sport 123 -j MASQUERADE --random
```

Note that iptables NAT is *stateful* (even for UDP) – the first packet goes through the `nat` table and causes a 'flow' entry to be created in the conntrack database, and all further packets matching that entry immediately use the cached information without re-checking the rules at all. (This is also what allows iptables to automatically un-SNAT/un-MASQUERADE incoming reply packets.)

For UDP, the conntrack entries don't last long – by default they expire after 180 seconds of inactivity. You can also use `conntrack -D -p udp --orig-port-src 123` to manually delete all NTP-related flow entries and force the NAT rules to be re-checked.

---

Alternatively, use an (S)NTP client which already dynamically chooses the local port. I think both Chrony and systemd-timesyncd will do so without causing any problems.

Comment: I think DNAT would better fit OP needs.

Comment: OP specifically mentioned the src_port, and DNAT does the opposite. Yes, it is actually not uncommon for NTP packets to have _both_ sport=123 and dport=123, usually when the NTP client is working in "peer" mode of some kind, and yes, I have also seen this conflict with ISP-level blocking (when the intent is to prevent customers from accidentally running open NTP servers).

Comment: Yes, sorry. I misunderstood OP post and setup.

Comment: Hi grawity, I added below into my iptables, but the packet count didn't increase.
**iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o erouter0 -p udp --sport 123 -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 2345**

Comment: Hi grawity, I noticed that sometime the rule work. I capture the NTP packet and its source port change from 123 to 2345. Then I removed the rule(2345) and added rule(3456), but the source port always be 2345 now...

Comment: iptables NAT rules are stateful – they don't transform each packet separately; only the _first_ packet goes through the rules and tells conntrack to transform the whole flow. All further packets just use the "cached" conntrack information and don't go through the nat table at all... So either wait a few minutes for the flow state to expire, or just run **`conntrack -D -p udp --orig-port-src 123`** to make it immediately forget all NTP flows.